# Using CodeIgniter Directory Map Helper

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm trying to figure out how to use this directory_map function in CodeIgniter.
See the manual for more details here: http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/directory_helper.html

Here is what I have working (kind of) and the result bellow:

```
$this->load->helper('directory');
$map = directory_map('textfiles/');

$index = '';

foreach ($map as $dir => $file) {
  $idx .= "<p> dir: {$dir} </p> <p> file: {$file} </p>";
} #foreach

return $idx;
```

My testing environment directory and files structure:

```
one [directory]
  subone [sub-directory]
    testsubone.txt [file-in-sub-directory]
  testone.txt [file-in-directory-one]
three [directory]
  testthree.txt [file-in-directory-three]
two [directory]
  testing [sub-directory]
    testagain.txt [file-in-sub-directory-testing]
  test.txt [file-in-directory-testing]
test.txt [file]
```

This is the output result I have in my view:

```
dir: 0
dir: two
file: Array
dir: three
file: Array
dir: 1
file: test.txt
dir: one
file: Array
```

As you can see in this result that not all directories or files are listed, some are showing up as an array.

There is also something called "get_filenames" function in file helper. Maybe it can be used somehow with directory_map.

Also, I get this following errors:

```
A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice
Message: Array to string conversion
Filename: welcome.php
Line Number: #
```

Any help will be greatly appreceated. Thank you =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're issue is that you're trying to print out a multi dimensionnal array.

You should try doing this instead :
With depth count http://codepad.org/y2qE59XS

```
$map = directory_map("./textfiles/");

function print_dir($in,$depth)
{
    foreach ($in as $k => $v)
    {
        if (!is_array($v))
            echo "<p>",str_repeat("&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;",$depth)," ",$v," [file]</p>";
        else
            echo "<p>",str_repeat("&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;",$depth)," <b>",$k,"</b> [directory]</p>",print_dir($v,$depth+1);
    }
}

print_dir($map,0);
```

Edit, Another version without depth count: http://codepad.org/SScJqePV

```
function print_dir($in)
{
    foreach ($in as $k => $v)
    {
        if (!is_array($v))
            echo "[file]: ",$v,"\n";
        else
            echo "[directory]: ",$k,"\n",print_dir($v);
    }
}

print_dir($map);
```

Please, be more specific with the output you want.

Edit on Comment
This one keeps the path track http://codepad.org/AYDIfLqW

```
function print_dir($in,$path)
{
    foreach ($in as $k => $v)
    {
        if (!is_array($v))
            echo "[file]: ",$path,$v,"\n";
        else
            echo "[directory]: ",$path,$k,"\n",print_dir($v,$path.$k.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);
    }
}

print_dir($map,'');
```

Last Edit
Returning function http://codepad.org/PEG0yuCr

```
function print_dir($in,$path)
{
    $buff = '';
    foreach ($in as $k => $v)
    {
        if (!is_array($v))
            $buff .= "[file]: ".$path.$v."\n";
        else
            $buff .= "[directory]: ".$path.$k."\n".print_dir($v,$path.$k.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);
    }
    return $buff;
}
```

Comment: http://codepad.org/y2qE59XS This is the output with your entry array... I don't get what you want to print out then ?! Can you give an example of what output do you want to ?

Comment: Just use `$map = directory_map("./textfiles/")` Instead?

Comment: Yes I know, I've used your "print_dir" function with $this->load->helper('directory'); $map = directory_map('./textfiles/'); $this->print_dir($map);  But All I got for the output is only ONE directory and ONE file. [file]: test.txt [directory]: two

Comment: You changed the **namespace** of this function, you need to change it *INTO* the function aswell. Replace the line by `echo "[directory]: ",$k,"\n",$this->print_dir($v);`

Comment: Check edition, you'll have the basis you want. Good luck for next steps

Comment: Could you please clefify this by using actual <a href=""></a> links and return instead of echo ?

Comment: Check edition. I guess you are smart enough to add `<a></a>` to this function. Good Luck

Comment: Actually I've tried that aproach before, but I guess its before I've added $this oh well. Thanks it works now =)